# How to change a key stored on a keydisk so it can decrypt a drive on OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, disk-encryption

Following the guide from https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#softraidFDEkeydisk I know how to encrypt a drive and store a key on a usb stick.

Suppose I've lost a copy of the key or suspect someone made a copy of it, how can I change the key stored on the usb stick so the new one will decrypt the previously encrypted drive?

To make things clear, I assume I still have a copy of the keydisk that allows me to decrypt the drive. My goal here is to avoid reinstalling OBSD and just re-encrypt the drive with a different key.

Manual says there is an option to change the passphrase on a crypto volume: https://man.openbsd.org/bioctl#P
so I thought it is also possible to change the key on a keydisk.

Comment: why do you think that you can decrypt the drive with a different key?

Comment: @jsotola I don't, that is why in the case as described above I would like to re-encrypt the whole drive with a new passphrase/key. My primary goal here is to avoid reinstalling OBSD and since I would have a copy of the key/pass I thought it was possible.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't, or at least not with the tools now available.  `bioctl` doesn't allow changing keydisks, only passphrases.  However, you can use passfiles (which might be stored on a USB disk, obviously).

This issue came up some time ago on `misc@openbsd.org`.  Take a look at the [entire thread](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-misc&m=144802821309487&w=2), especially at the replies by Ted Unangst, as there are some caveats.  Notably, changing passwords isn't the same as re-encrypting the disk, so, changing passwords might not do exactly what one thinks it does.